# Run an exe from batch file with parameters

Tags: batch, emulator, arguments

My younger brother loves to play a game on Sega Emulator: Gens.exe
He uses some cheats as well in the game-genie section of the emulator.
[image: Gens Emulator for Sega Games]
Opening game rom and adding cheats later on, is difficult for him at his age.

What i want is to make him a batch file, which will automatically open the ROM (.smd file) and will
add some cheats after opening the ROM.

For instance, i want the batch file to open the ROM "Contra_Hard Corps.smd"
and add following two cheats in Game Genie section

**CheatCode | Name**
AM4A-AA8C | No Weapon Loss
ADXT-A60L | Super Jump

The Game Genie window looks like this:
[image: Game Genie window]

You can get the emulator from link:
http://www.emulator-zone.com/doc.php/genesis/

You can get ROM from this link:
https://wowroms.com/en/roms/sega-genesis-megadrive/contra-hard-corps-usa/25433.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a batch file with the following contents and place in the same folder with `gens.exe` and the `smd` ROM file.

If you want to change the ROM file also change the name in the batch file appeared at two places preserving the file extensions.

```bat
(
echo AM4A-AA8C No Weapon Loss
echo ADXT-A60L Super Jump
)>"Contra - Hard Corps (USA, Korea).pat"

echo Pat file created. 

start "" gens.exe "Contra - Hard Corps (USA, Korea).smd"
```

Comment: Your script does the job very well. I am going to accept your script as my answer.
But before that, i need to know, if it was not for the .pat file, would we still be able to add cheats to the Game Genie window?

Comment: I thought by getting an answer to my question, i would be able to input values to any program via a batch file. But in this case, there is a .pat file which the emulator reads before launching the game. Is there any other way?

Comment: @AhsanTaqveem Before discovered this way I tried [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) and it was somehow worked  but need some bug tracing. https://www.codepile.net/pile/8W8AlMOM

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. It helped :)
Farewell.